# PHP Get Domain With http

Tags: php, parse-url

I want to get Get Domain from URL and be output: `http://www.domain.com/`

I found this, but does not come out with the `http://`

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.lebanonpost.com/2012/05/20/press-754/';
$parse = parse_url($url);
$domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
print $parse['host']; // prints 'google.com'
?>
```

Output: `www.lebanonpost.com`

I want it to be: `http://www.lebanonpost.com/`

Comment: Concate the missing stuff to your output.

Comment: add 'http://' to $domain.  I suggest a basic php tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
print $parse['scheme'] . '://' . $parse['host'];
```

*It will work if there is `https` instead of `http`*

### Test Here

Comment: Or even `ftp` :o Oh, the possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

You can concate `http://` to your output:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.lebanonpost.com/2012/05/20/press-754/';
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
    $domainURL = $parse['scheme'].'://'.$parse['host'].'/';
    print $domainURL;
?>
```

Comment: You missed the slash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is the resource I always use for printing url's with PHP - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891890/1964113

This answer breaks down each piece, even http/https and #fragments.

Google these things man! Really easy to find.